# Browser detection booleans mess. Caché plugin?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, globals

[image: Browser detection error]

Hello, I have an issue concerning the Browser Detection Booleans. Sometimes, being in Chrome or Firefox, the page is served as being in IE, as in the attached image.

Can this be related to the fact that I have the **W3 Total Cache** installed and running?
If it is, is there a way to prevent this plugin from doing so?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have caching enabled then the HTML is saved from a previous visit. That's what caching is. You need caching for acceptable performance, which is why trying to use the user agent to add HTML classes for each browser is not a good idea. The fact that `$is_macIE` is in there shows how dated this practice is, and it's telling that WordPress itself does not use these variables for anything. There are far better ways to deal with browser compatibility than a body class.

Comment: Okay, thank you Jacob, any hint where to start?

Comment: No. I don’t even know what particular problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: I would like to detect the visitor's browser in wordpress even when using caché.

Comment: So you’re ignoring the rest of my comment? You almost certainly don’t need a class for the user’s browser. What problem are you trying to solve by adding this class?

Comment: What do you want to use the browser information for? There's almost certainly a more reliable and modern way to accomplish your end goal, if you'll share what you want to actually do with the data. :)

Comment: Many times I use the browser info in the body class to address issues that may appear when visiting the web from different browsers. But in this particular case I want to show a message saying that IE is not supported.